# Why is creating a GraphicsDevice causing an "unexpected error" on instantiation?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to embed a bare bones XNA application in a Winforms MDI application, and I seem to be having issues.  I am following the example of http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1 and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

In my MDI parent I am instantiating the rendering form via:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var render = new RenderForm();
        render.MdiParent = this;
        render.Show();
    }
```

The code for my rendering form is:

```
public class RenderForm : Form
{
    private XnaRenderer _renderer;

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
            _renderer = new XnaRenderer(Handle, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);

        base.OnCreateControl();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _renderer.RenderScene(null);
    }
}
```

So when the form is created, it attempts to create an instance of my `XnaRenderer` class.  `ClientSize.Width` is 284 and `ClientSize.Height` is 261, and the `Handle` looks to be valid.   The constructor's code is:

```
    public XnaRenderer(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
    {
        _graphicsService = new GraphicsDeviceService(windowHandle, width, height);

        SetViewport(width, height);
    }
```

The `GraphicsDeviceService` class is essentially the same as the one from the example code, but it's made to not be a singleton.  The code for the constructor is:

```
    public GraphicsDeviceService(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
    {
        _presentationParams = new PresentationParameters
        {
            BackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color,
            BackBufferHeight = Math.Max(height, 1),
            BackBufferWidth = Math.Max(width, 1),
            DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24,
            DeviceWindowHandle = windowHandle,
            PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate
        };

        _graphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter, GraphicsProfile.Reach,
                                             _presentationParams);
    }
```

However, when the `GraphicsDevice` object is instantiated I get the following `InvalidOperationException`:

> An unexpected error has occurred.

There is no more to the exception's message and no inner exception, making this pretty hard to debug without a lot of XNA knowledge.

Does anyone see something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your _presentationParams valid?
Also, does anything need to be created before GraphicsDevice?

These are the things I would be checking.

Comment: What do you mean by valid?  It's an instantiated object

Comment: "The `GraphicsDeviceService` class is essentially the same as the one from the example code, but it's made to not be a singleton." <- I'm curious as to why you made this change?

Comment: I wasn't sure what benefit there was to having it as a singleton if I'm only having one display

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

In my building of the presentation parameters, I needed to add `IsFullScreen = false`.

Would have been much easier to figure out if it gave a good exception message

Comment: really? I use XNA in WinForms but I though this parameter couldn't cause this bug.

Comment: Not sure why.  Maybe because it's not a valid resolution for full screen and thus it's crashing.  I wish I had a better error code or something to know exactly why this caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using `OnHandleCreated` instead of `OnCreateControl`:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated()
{
    if (!DesignMode)
        _renderer = new XnaRenderer(Handle, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);

    base.OnHandleCreated ();
}
```

if it does not work, try using `HiDef` profile instead of `Reach` profile.

Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong.